# Why click() doesn't work on object tag <object>?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make an extension for google chrome. It will automatically click on the speaker icon in the google dictionary's result to make it pronounces the word automatically.

http://www.google.com/dictionary?langpair=en|en&q=love&hl=en&aq=f

i'm using this code: document.getElementById("pronunciation").click()

however, i wonder why it doesn't work? actually  tag does support the standard methods - as w3schools wrote: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_object.asp

Can you suggest any method in order to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the object is flash, sending it a click event will not work unless Google built click support into the flash file -- which they apparently didn't.

However, the actual audio file is a parameter to the flash program, and linked to in a child node.

For the given example, it is: "http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/love.mp3".
This can be obtained with:

```
var soundFile = document.querySelector ("#pronunciation a").href;
```

Then pass this file to a library, such as [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), and your script can play it automatically (may your coworkers/family have mercy on your soul. :) ).

Comment: +1 for the querySelector. i didn't know that we can query the child node :)

Answer (score 1):

The play icon is a flash player.

Most likely the onclick event isn't on the stage (i don't know if that would even work with a click on the object) but on a element inside the flash.